# undefined reference when compiling in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, undefined

ok so i have this code that is supposed to read text from a file and do some computation which is not too important for this question. When I try to compile it I get this error(file name is pp3.c)

```
/tmp/ccnZaQld.o:pp3.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined refrence to 'sovle' 
/tmp/ccnZaQld.o:pp3.c:(.text+0x5f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol 'solve'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

char buff[SIZE][SIZE];
int initialize();
int read(char*);
int findstart();
int sovle(int,int,int,int);
int printmaze();
int posx, posy, oldposy, oldposx;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    initialize();
    read(argv[1]);
    findstart();
    if(sovle(posx, posy,oldposy,oldposx))
        printmaze();
    else
        printf("maze is unsolveable");
}

int initialize(){
    int i;
    int m;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(m=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            buff[i][m]='0';
        }
    } 
}

int read(char* m88){
    FILE* myfile = fopen(m88, "r");
    int linenum = 0;
    while(fgets(buff[linenum], SIZE, myfile)!=NULL){
        linenum++;
    }
    fclose(myfile);
}

int findstart(){
    int i,m;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(m=0; i<SIZE; i++){
            if (buff[i][m]== 'S'){
                posx = m;
                posy = i;
                oldposy = i;
                oldposx = m;
                return 1;
            }   
        }
    } 
}

int solve(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy){
    if(buff[y][x+1] != 'x' && x+1 != oldposx){
        if(buff[y][x+1] == '$')return 1;
        if(solve(y,x+1,y,x)){
            buff[y][x+1] = '*';
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(buff[y][x-1] != 'x' && x-1 != oldposx){
        if(buff[y][x-1] == '$')return 1;
        if(solve(y,x-1,y,x)){
            buff[y][x-1] = '*';
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(buff[y+1][x] != 'x' && y+1 != oldposy){
        if(buff[y+1][x] == '$')return 1;
        if(solve(y+1,x,y,x)){
            buff[y+1][x] = '*';
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(buff[y-1][x] != 'x' && y-1 != oldposy){
        if(buff[y-1][x] == '$')return 1;
        if(solve(y-1,x,y,x)){
            buff[y-1][x] = '*';
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int printmaze(){
    int i;
    while(buff[i][0]!= '0'){
        printf("%s", buff[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message kind of tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your source. `sovle` is not `solve`:

The one it's complaining about is here:

```
if(sovle(posx, posy,oldposy,oldposx))
    printmaze();
```

It doesn't help that you've declared the typo as being a function:

```
int findstart();
int sovle(int,int,int,int);
int printmaze();
```

Comment: damn thats a really dumb mistake on my part im going to delete this thread but i thank you very much for taking your time to help me.